# Error when trying to use a shared library in a qml file

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries, qml

I'm trying to use a shared library in a QML file. Everything seems to be good but when I compile I get this error:

> error: 'QObject' is an inaccessible base of 'Player'

I'll really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks.

This is the code of the shared library:
`player.h`

```
class PLAYERSHARED_EXPORT Player : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    QString name;
    Q_PROPERTY(QString id READ getId WRITE setId NOTIFY idChanged)
    QString id;

public:
    Player(QString name);
    const QString getName();
    void setName(const QString name);
    const QString getId();
    void setId(const QString id);

signals:
    void nameChanged();
    void idChanged();
};
```

and the `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    resources.qrc
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
include(deployment.pri)
OTHER_FILES +=
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/dlls/ -lplayer
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/dlls
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/dlls
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared private `QObject` inheritance.  Change to:

```
class PLAYERSHARED_EXPORT Player : public QObject
```